# How to get exactly one element from an unordered_set?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have:

```
    std::unordered_set<ObjectRepresentation*> incompletePieces;
```

I would like to get exactly one object from the unordered_set. To do that I am using a for loop, and "break", at the end of the loop so that the loop runs at most once.

```
    while (incompletePieces.size()){
        for (auto containedPiece : incompletePieces){ //Warning at this line that loop will run at most once
            //  .... doing some stuff with the contained piece
            incompletePieces.erase(containedPiece);

                    break;
        }
    }
```

This is the desired behaviour that I want. The problem is that the compiler shows a warning:

> Loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed)

How do I rewrite my code so that the warning goes away ? Is there a better way to get an item from the unordered_set ?

Comment: As per my understanding, there's only one contrainedPiece per incompletePieces instance and hence the warning. If that's the case, you may not even write the inner for loop.

Comment: @SaCh No, I think you've misunderstood. There are many containedPieces, but i use the for loop to extract just one at a time. Within the for loop I delete the containedPiece, so the number of items in the incomplePieces is reduced, so the outer while loop eventually goes down to zero and terminates.

Comment: The problem is that your for loop ends with an unconditional break. Why do you even have a loop there? If you just want to access the first element, use the `front()` member function. Also, don't make `size()` the condition of the while loop, use `!empty()`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I am fixing someone elses code. I don't know why it was written this way. I am guessing it originally ran many times, but when it was updated to require just one object they just added a break, because it was quick to update the code.

Comment: Correction to myself: associative containers don't have `front()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `begin()` to get the first element.

```
if (incompletePieces.size() > 0)
    auto containedPiece = *(incompletePieces.begin());
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you presented does in fact process *all* elements and clears the set of them as it gets done, but it does so in a highly unidiomatic way.

There are two idiomatic ways of doing this, depending on whether processing an element could modify the set itself.

1) If the "doing some stuff" code is guaranteed to not touch `incompletePieces` (i.e. completing one piece does not create additional incomplete pieces), then the idiomatic and efficient solution is to just loop over the set and clear it afterwards:

```
for (auto piece : incompletePieces) {
  // process piece
}
incompletePieces.clear();
```

2) If this is not the case, or you really need to clear elements as you go, then the idiomatic solution is still iterator based looping:

```
auto it = incompletePieces.begin();
while (it != incompletePieces.end()) {
  // process *it
#if C++11
  it = incompletePieces.erase(it);
#else
  auto prev = it++;
  incompletePieces.erase(prev);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Actually, the code posted above is edited from the original - the original has a lot of code doing some complex unintuitive stuff that is hard to explain. The only thing I'm trying to do is just use something besides a for loop / break to get a single item from the set.

Comment: I'd still recommend the second way of doing it. It is functionally identical to the `while(size())` loop. But there is certainly value in doing only the absolute minimum of changes to an existing complex codebase.

Comment: ok, thanks!! (some more characters to pass the limit so I can post)

Answer (score 2):

Whereas `*unordered_set::begin()` will give you first element (no `unordered_set::front()`),

I would rewrite:

```
while (incompletePieces.size()){
    for (auto containedPiece : incompletePieces){
        //  .... doing some stuff with the contained piece
        incompletePieces.erase(containedPiece);
        break;
    }
}
```

into:

```
for (auto* containedPiece : incompletePieces){
    //  .... doing some stuff with the contained piece
}
incompletePieces.clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the code as below:

```
for(auto* containedPiece : incompletePieces){
     //Process the set contents
}
//Clear entire set in one go 
incompletePieces.clear();
```

If you want to clear it one by one, you would have to use iterators as shown below:

```
 auto it = incompletePieces.begin(); //Take the pointer to first element of set
 for( ; it !=incompletePieces.end() ; it++){ 
     incompletePieces.erase(*it); //Erase one element at a time
 }
```